# Using fread and fwrite .. data loss

Tags: c

Hi I am trying to read a binary file and process it but I think I am using fread wrong way, when I try to use fread the no. of bytes read are less then the size of file. can anyone help me, white I am doing wrong

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <limits.h>

    int main()
    {

    FILE *fin=fopen("./file.pcap","rb");

    char line[LINE_MAX];

    FILE *fout=fopen("out.txt","w");

    while(fread(line,sizeof(line),1,fin)){
        fwrite(&line,sizeof(line),1,fout);
    }

    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);

    }
```

The first file is around 51236 and out.txt is 51200

Comment: If you're reading in binary mode (`rb`), then you probably want to write in binary mode (`wb`) too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fread returns the number of "elements" read.  You have said an element is `LINE_MAX` bytes long, so when you get to the end of the file, there is not a full element for you, so `fread()` returns 0 and your output ends up truncated.

try flipping to read "a number of bytes" rather than "1 block of LINE_MAX bytes":

```
size_t numBlocks;
while((numBlocks = fread(line, 1, sizeof(line), fin)) > 0) {
    fwrite(line, 1, numBlocks, fout);
}
```

Comment: You almost got a downvote for your nefarious use of `int` :-)

Comment: ...but I noticed it just in time... - Pick the guy who hasn't been programming in C for quite a few years ;-)

Comment: Thank you...it was my mistake to not check return value.. and I was thinking why the hell size of output changes everytime I change the buffer size

Answer (score 2):

Because you're asking for `LINE-MAX`-sized blocks, you won't get the final one if the file size isn't an *exact* multiple of that value. `fread` returns the number of complete *blocks* that it read. You would be better off using something like:

```
size_t sz;
while ((sz = fread (line, 1, sizeof (line), fin)) > 0) {
    fwrite (line, sz, 1, fout);
}
```

This will read *any* amount of data (up to `LINE_MAX`) from the input file and then write a block of that size out to the output file. It does so because, instead of saying one block of size `LINE_MAX`, you specify `LINE_MAX` blocks each of one byte. That way, if there aren't `LINE_MAX` characters left in the file, `fread` will just give you as many as it can.

The end of file will result in `fread` returning zero, any other value means data was read successfully.

> As an aside, you should also check the return value from `fwrite`. You don't have to swap the arguments for that one but you should ensure that the return value is `1` (or `sz` if you *do* swap the arguments). Otherwise, the data wasn't necessarily all written.

In other words:

```
size_t sz;
while ((sz = fread (line, 1, sizeof (line), fin)) > 0) {
    if (fwrite (line, sz, 1, fout) != 1) {
        // Handle error.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but `fread()` is going to return `0` when it gets the partial buffer at the end of your input file.  You need to add some code to handle that case, or else you'll skip writing those bytes out.

The `&` in your `fwrite()` call is also unnecessary, but that's not related to your problem.